# Are microformats2 the "standard" for SEO and RDFa and Microdata deprecated today?

Tags: structured-data, microdata, standards, rdfa, microformats

I came to [a years old post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/what-are-the-advantages-of-schema-orgs-microdata-vs-microformats-et-al?_gl=1*1qe140y*_ga*MTEzNTUzODUyNS4xNjYzMTQ2NTA1*_ga_WCZ03SZFCQ*MTY2MzkyMzMyMS4zNC4xLjE2NjM5MjM0MDEuMC4wLjA.), discussing [Microdata](https://microformats.org/wiki/microdata), [RDFa](https://microformats.org/wiki/rdfa) etc.
I looked on the microformats2 site and it says both have been superseded by microformats2. Also Google uses microformats2 for SEO.

Should I only use microformats2 these days if I want to start with SEO? Is it the de facto "standard"? There are extra HTML5 tags to sort of "mark" content as some type of microformat, e.g new tags like `<time>` and `<article>`. Do those tags have the same meaning or relevance for search engines like if I would tag them directly with microformat classes (like class="h-article", etc.)?

Comment: The only tangible SEO benefit to structured data is when you get a special display in the search results known as a rich snippet.  [Google has a list of possible rich snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery).  Using structured data won't help your site rank better or entice Google to index more of your pages.

Answer (score 1):

> Also Google uses microformats2 for SEO.

You are wrong. Google says:

> Google Search supports structured data in the following formats,
> unless documented otherwise:
>
> - JSON-LD* (Recommended)
> - Microdata
> - RDFa

Their guide **[Search Engine Optimization (SEO) Starter Guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/beginner/seo-starter-guide)** does not mention structured data format

Comment: hmm true, I thought I'd seen it somewhere... was probably wrong